# Security for on-prem/cloud REST Application

Tags: rest, security, ssl, authorization, iot

I've been reading security articles for several days, but have no formal training in the field. I am developing a configuration and management application for an IoT device. It is meant to be run either on an internal network, or accessed over the web.

My application will be used by IT admins, managers, and factory-floor workers. Depending on the installation, there will be varying levels of infrastructure in place. It could run on a laptop on the floor itself, on a server, or hosted in the cloud. For this reason, **we can not assume that our clients will have the kind of infrastructure you might find at a datacenter or in the cloud, for example CAS or NTP.**

Our application provides a REST API for client applications to gather data. We'd like to use roles to restrict what data users can access. I've gathered that a common solution for authentication is to encode the username/pass in the REST Header. However, this is completely insecure unless sent over a secure channel.

As I understand it, SSL Certification Authorities grant certs for a specific domain. Our application will have no set domain, and a different IP depending on the installation. Many web applications do not trust self-signed certs. **It's not clear to me whether a self-signed application is good enough for a typical application-developer who will be consuming our interface.**

With this being the case:

***1) What are my options to set up a secure channel, internally or via the web?***

***2) Am I making assumptions about how our product will be used that damage our users' security unnecessarily?***

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use custom encryption to encrypt the data being sent to the applications.

You can also use JSON web tokens to secure your REST API. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token. The JSON tokens could be generated by a centralized authentication server and included in all requests sent by the client applications to the server